# Get name of lambda function as string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, function, lambda

I have a defined a lambda function as

```
my_lambda = lambda { |x| 100 * x }
```

I am passing this function as an input to another function which needs to verify its identify, something like:

```
def function_verifier(func)
  if func.to_s == "my_lambda"
    return "ok"
  else
    return "mismatch!"
  end
end
```

However when I pass `my_lambda` as input to this function, the command `func.to_s` returns `"#<Proc:0x0000a973516680@(pry):14 (lambda)>"` instead of `"my_lambda"`.

How do I turn the function handle for `my_lambda` into the string `"my_lambda"`?

Comment: have you tried to use to_s ?

Comment: That's actually what I called, not `to_str` (that was a typo). Just edited the post to clarify

Comment: Lambdas don't have names. Consider `a = -> { }; b = a`, what would you expect the name of the lambda to be and why? And what do you mean by "verify its identity"?

Comment: "verify its identity" meaning establishes that it does the same thing as the `my_lambda` function, I don't care if they're represented in the same spot in memory. Above I've given a toy version of what's actually going on. In reality the `function_verifier` performs different operations depending on what lambda functions are passed into it, where these operations are separate from the operation performed by the lambda functions themselves

Comment: But if lambda functions don't maintain any knowledge of their name, then I'm probably better off just refactoring my code.

Comment: @jon_simon yes you are. They cannot "maintain knowledge of their name" because they don't have a name you have simply assigned one to a local variable. If you wanted to "establish that [they do] the same thing" you would have to call both of them with an equality check

Comment: this concept of 'original variable name' is not something we have available to us. Maybe store the lambdas in a hash, keyed by name? E.g. `lambas = {foo: ->() {}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That won't work, because you are passing the `proc` to `function_verifer` and `proc` does not know the variable(s) whose value it is. You could do something like the following.

```
my_lambda = lambda { |x| 100 * x }
  #=> #<Proc:0x000000008a1790@(irb):746 (lambda)>
MY_LAMBDA_OBJECT_ID = my_lambda.object_id
  #=> 4525000

def function_verifier(func)
  func.object_id == MY_LAMBDA_OBJECT_ID ? "ok" : "mismatch!"
end

function_verifier(my_lambda)
  #=> "ok"

your_lambda = my_lambda
  #=> #<Proc:0x000000008a1790@(irb):746 (lambda)>
your_lambda.object_id
  #=> 4525000
function_verifier(your_lambda)
  #=> "ok"

my_lambda = lambda { |x| 99 * x }
  #=> #<Proc:0x000000009116d0@(irb):768 (lambda)>
my_lambda.object_id
  #=> 4754280
function_verifier(my_lambda)
  #=> "mismatch!"
```